# Enable UTF8 characters in IEx (Interactive Elixir Console) on Windows

Tags: windows, utf-8, console, elixir

how can enable UTF8 characters in IEx (Interactive Elixir Console) on windows?

Can't get the following to work:

```
# Strings are all encoded in UTF-8:
"héllò" #=> "héllò"
```

Comment: Just type `chcp 65001` before you start the tool.  Change the console font to something else than Terminal.

Comment: nope, doesn't work have tried it. tired pasting "héllò" in my console... still no luck

Comment: Do you get a better result by starting iex as `iex --werl`?

Comment: Either José or CharlesO you should post that comment as the answer so that if anyone else runs across this question they can see the answer easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Suggested in the comments, this works very well:

**`iex --werl`**

It does NOT require you to set any code page at all and you have UTF8 readily available.

I would suggest that the Elixir core docs be updated to point this really helpful switch **`--werl`**  out to other first time users.

Comment: Thanks @JoséValim - here's a [link to the docs](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/bin/iex)